# Building a DomNode from an xpath definition

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

Is there a way in PHP to create a DomElement, that will be added to a DomDocument later, from an xpath definition.

lets say,we have

```
$xpath = 'a:ul[@class="something]';
```

What i want in result, is DomElement containing :

```
<a:ul class="something"/>
```

Or, if :

```
$xpath = 'a';
//result <a/>
```

Another example :

```
$xpath = 'a:ul[@class="something and @id=abc]'; 
//result <a:ul class="something" id="abc"/>
```

Comment: Do you want `DomElement` containing following data `<a:ul class="something"/>` ?

Comment: Yes, then i have to add it to DomDocument created before

Answer (score 1):

Of course here is a way, but it is not really easy. You would have to define Xpath like language and a parser for it.

Here are a lot of features in Xpath that would be extremely difficult or impossible to expand to a DOM structure. A simple example would be `//*` - it matches any element node in the document, but it has no tag name that you could use to create a node.

So you would first have to define you own language that uses the same syntax as Xpath, but a lot less features.

Then you could create a parser for it and last use the DOM methods to create the XML nodes.